# Java Iterator on doubly linked list

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list

Hi I'm very new to Java and have this problem with building a nested Iterator class for a Doubly Linked List. I'm getting this error on E next method when running the test program. 
The goal of the next method in the Iterator is to return the next item in the Doubly Linked List.

Can anyone advice a fix on my code? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NullPointerException**    at
>   dlinkedlist.Deque$DoubleListIterator.next(Deque.java:51)

```
    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        last = current;
        E value = current.item;
        current = current.next; 
        index++;
        return value;
    }
    public void remove() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
  }// end class ListIterator
```

Comment: "next element" in what sence? Forward iteration or backward iteration? I believe you need a forward iteration here.

Comment: where is your line 51?

Comment: Yes, forward iteration, how do I accomplish that? And do I also need a backward method for the iterator? I'm still bit confused. Please help, thanks!

Comment: What is 'head' - your code snippet does not show such variable. Is the NPE thrown for the first call to 'next'? What is the dataset you insert to your list - give us more to analyze.

Comment: @Lrrr This is line 51:  E value = current.item;

Comment: @R4J updated, please kindly have a look, thanks!

Comment: @Robert, I am sorry but your snippet does not show what you are doing, how do you construct your Deque object etc. If you want us to help you out, you really need to put some effort into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `current` object is null. Can you check it?

Comment: Well, the class `Deque` is in-complete. It does not include most of the required methods to work as a proper dequeue. Maybe OP can check the algorithm here http://basicdatastructures.blogspot.in/2007/12/dequeue-data-structure.html

Comment: public Deque() {
    head = new Node();
    tail = new Node();
    head.next = tail;
    tail.prev = head;
    N = 0;
  }

Comment: Now it seems better. You should not get this exception now. :)

Comment: Sorry unfortunately I still get them, I suspect there must be something wrong with the E next method.

Comment: Where is your `add()` method which adds a new node in dequeue? Also, give complete stacktrace.