# Java Iterator Doubly Linked list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, doubly-linked-list, deque

Hi I'm very new to Java and trying to create a `Deque` class by implementing a doubly linked-list format. When I run the code(DequeApp), I get a  `NullPointerException` refer back to my Iterator.next(Deque.java:44).

```
Error messages:  **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dlist.Deque$DoubleListIterator.next(Deque.java:44)



        public E next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {throw new NoSuchElementException();}
                else{
                E temp = current.item;
                current = current.next;
                return temp;}
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Iterator on doubly linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023620/java-iterator-on-doubly-linked-list)

Comment: Very similar code (there are not that many ways to write linked lists...), @Aakash, although the index is incremented correctly there.

Comment: I understand that the algorithm would be same and most implementations would also be same, but the OP has asked same question in 2 different places, with same problem. He is getting NPE for which the solution was already provided. Though I have marked the question as duplicate, I also gave the solution to the problem myself as well.

Comment: Yes sorry that i asked the question twice, it's just that I didn't fully understand the other post, sorry I'm only starting to learn java, will hopefully get better at it, thanks Aakash!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made two changes.

1. As tucuxi already told, increment index.
2. Start current from head, not head.next.

   ```
   private class DoubleListIterator implements Iterator<E> {
   // instance variable
   private Node current = head;
   private int index = 0;

   public boolean hasNext() {
       return index < N;
   }

   public E next() {
       if (!hasNext()) {
           throw new NoSuchElementException();
       } else {
           index++;
           E temp = current.item;
           current = current.next;
           return temp;
       }
   }

   public void remove() {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Most welcome. But @tucuxi said right. Build debugging habit and make sure everything is in place where they should be.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to increment your `index` counter in the `DoubleListIterator`. You write:

```
public E next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        E temp = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

And you should have written:

```
public E next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        index ++; // <---- without this, hasNext() always returns true
        E temp = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Note also that I have changed the indenting format to that of Oracle's guidelines.

A second error is that you initialize your Iterator as follows:

```
    private Node current=head.next;
```

However, this makes it impossible to retrieve `head` (as you are already pointing to its `next` node). And it makes you index counter off-by-one. Corrected code:

```
    private Node current=head;
```

Comment: Hi tucuxi, sorry I'm still getting the same exception. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at dlist.Deque$DoubleListIterator.next(Deque.java:46)      Which is this line "E temp = current.item;"

Comment: Found another error further up. You should really do a full pass with a debugger making sure everything looks good; untested code is always full of errors on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to using index variable is

Maybe you could try  "current.next != null" within hasNext.

But if it is already working with index no issues then.